# datetime strptime works in one time but not another similar time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

This works:

```
datetime.strptime('Wed Aug 22 01:08:39 2018', '%a %b %d %H:%m:%S %Y')
```

But this doesn't:

```
datetime.strptime('Wed Aug 22 01:14:01 2018', '%a %b %d %H:%m:%S %Y')
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful with your format string. `%m` stands for month as a zero-padded decimal, not minutes. Use `%M` instead:

```
datetime.strptime('Wed Aug 22 01:14:01 2018', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

The first example works because `'08'` will translate to August while, of course, there is no 14th month. See [Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/) for a complete reference.